# Deleting the last node of a singly linkedlist

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

Below is the function to delete the last node of a singly linked list.
I don't understand, why are we creating a temp Node? I tried doing it without the temp Node and used the node itself but the output doesn't delete the last node.
Also, since we are using the temp Node, why are we returning the node and not temp? We aren't making any changes to node, so how is node affected?

```
public Node deleteLastNode(Node node)
{
    if (node.next == null || node == null)
        return null;
    Node temp = node;

    while (temp.next.next != null)
    {
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    temp.next = null;
    return node;
}
```

Comment: Without temp node how would you iterate through list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand why we are creating a temp Node?

That's because you're storing current iteration node in that `temp` variable.

> I tried doing it without the temp Node and used the node itself but the output doesn't delete the last node.

Code needed to provide any feedback.

> Also, since we are using the temp Node, why are we returning node and not temp?

Because you're returning reference to the head of the list, it just doesn't have last element anymore.

> We aren't making any changes to node which so how is node getting affected?

You're deleting last node here
`temp.next = null;`

Hope it makes things a little bit clear for you.

Comment: For iterating through the linked list why can't we use the node itself. For example what if I write the while loop as while (node.next.next != null) and don't create a temp variable at all. Why doesn't that work?

Comment: @Bobert, because you will lost head of the list

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `temp` node is usually used is that the `node` is the head/starting of the list, which is the only representation of the list we have (by definition of a linked list). Hence we do not want to alter the head(or representation of our list) and that is the reason `node` is returned from the method - which means we are returning the updated list after deletion is performed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to switch this to conditions like this

```
if (node.next == null || node == null) to 
if (node == null || node.next == null)
```

this may cause null pointer exception.
next..I think that temp is need to hold data before assigning null so that the real reference would not loose data.

Answer (score 0):

To navigate linked list to its last node, you need a pointer (cursor) pointing at a node you are supposing to be last pending the test `this.next == null`.

Without the temporary node (a.k.a cursor, or pointer) how could you interact with any node in the list?

Comment: For iterating through the linked list why can't we use the node itself. For example what if I write the while loop as while (node.next.next != null) and don't create a temp variable at all. Why doesn't that work? You would still be iterating through the list right?